# Radius proxy append reply message

Tags: radius, freeradius

we have a radius proxy server which will receive request from different realm and forward to different radius server to process authentication and accounting stuff. Normally the reply message is sent out by the target radius server, we are now facing a problem that one of the target radius server cannot reply session timeout message.

So we are wondering if it is possible to append a session timeout message and together with the reply message sent out by the target radius server to requester?

we are using free radius.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the authorize section (sites-available/default) use the 'update' unlang stanza.

```
update reply {
    Session-Timeout := "<timeout>"
}
```

If you want to make it conditional on the upstream proxy sending you messages:

```
if ("%{client:Shortname}" == '<client name>') {
    <update>
}
```